# Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection now occurring after running OK

Tags: r

I have tried to rerun some programs which worked perfectly well before, and  most of them use the same call as below but now none of them work.

It could be a latent problem with the code come to life or it is something within my overall environment that has changed.

I have tried reloading the complete directory  from archive from 2 months ago when I was using the programmes and they do not work now.

After reading the previous answers I have tried

setwd("Documents/Paper1/ThirdDraft/DTW_DATA")`

to make data and program folders peers but R will not let me change it.

I am an occasional user of R and not conversant with the environment so some hints / advice on a possible approach would be very helpful.

Thank you

The data files are at `Documents/Paper1/ThirdDraft/DTW_DATA/Binned_Base_Data`
working directory at /Users/briank/Documents/Paper1/ThirdDraft/DTW_DATA/DTW_R_Programmes`

```
#
# Import Data 
#

chan11Data <-   read.csv("Documents/Paper1/ThirdDraft/DTW_DATA/Binned_Base_Data/Channel_11.csv",
+           header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)

Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

In addition: Warning message:

In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'Documents/Paper1/ThirdDraft/DTW_DATA/Binned_Base_Data/Channel_11.csv': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Replace `+ header = TRUE` with just `header = TRUE`

Comment: Also try `file.choose()` if you have issues finding the exact path that R needs. It will allow you to pick a file interactively.

Comment: I am embarrassed at my oversight -- your responses are very appreciate

Answer (score 1):

If your working directory is

```
/Users/briank/Documents/Paper1/ThirdDraft/DTW_DATA/DTW_R_Programmes
```

Then R won't find this file

```
"Documents/Paper1/ThirdDraft/DTW_DATA/Binned_Base_Data/Channel_11.csv"
```

but it should be able to find

```
"/Users/briank/Documents/Paper1/ThirdDraft/DTW_DATA/Binned_Base_Data/Channel_11.csv"
```

or

```
"../Binned_Base_Data/Channel_11.csv"
```

Answer (score -1):

You are mixing up absolute and relative file paths, and that as a consequence, you are implementing bad coding practices that result in the kind of trouble that you are facing right now.

To be clear,

```
/Users/briank/Documents/Paper1/ThirdDraft/DTW_DATA/
```

is an absolute file path that starts at the root of your disk, whereas

```
Documents/Paper1/ThirdDraft/DTW_DATA
```

is a *relative* file path that will start in your working directory.

### Your current predicament

1. Since everything that you are doing happens in the following directory, that directory should be your working directory:

   `/Users/briank/Documents/Paper1/ThirdDraft/DTW_DATA/`

   If you are using [RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/), which I recommend you do, then I recommend that you create a Project in that directory. Opening the Rroject (e.g. `DTW_DATA.Rproj`) will automatically set the working directory to the path above (i.e. what you did with `setwd`).
2. Now, within that directory, you seem to have two directories:

   - `DTW_R_Programmes` – which is where I suppose your R scripts are located
   - `Binned_Base_Data` – which is where your data, e.g. `Channel_11.csv`, are located

### A possible fix

If you opened your R script by double-clicking it, it is likely that your working directory was set to `DTW_R_Programmes` -- in which case you need to "go back" one level to find your data, as in

```
../Binned_Base_Data/Channel_11.csv
```

### Another possible fix

Instead of using `../` as above, the solution I would like to recommend is to **move all your R scripts to the root directory of your project, i.e. `DTW_DATA`.** That should limit confusion in the future, and make your project more manageable.

What you want to have is

```
DTW_DATA/

  1_a_script.r
  2_another_script.r
  etc.

  Binned_Base_Data/

    Channel_11.csv
    Channel_12.csv
    etc.
```

Then, in your script(s), just indicate

```
d <- read.csv("Binned_Base_Data/Channel_11.csv")
```

… and enjoy the sheer simplicity of it.

> If the first line of your #rstats script is "setwd(..." I will come into your lab and SET YOUR COMPUTER ON FIRE. -- [Twitter](https://twitter.com/tpoi/status/720340395901648897)